# It looks like C code in Python C-API returns ptr to stack variable. What am I missing?

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I was reading through the file methodobject.c, because I'm trying to learn about making C extensions for Python, when I saw the following code snippet:

```
PyObject *
PyCFunction_Call(PyObject *func, PyObject *arg, PyObject *kw)
{
    PyCFunctionObject* f = (PyCFunctionObject*)func;
    PyCFunction meth = PyCFunction_GET_FUNCTION(func);
    PyObject *self = PyCFunction_GET_SELF(func);
    Py_ssize_t size;

    switch (PyCFunction_GET_FLAGS(func) & ~(METH_CLASS | METH_STATIC | METH_COEXIST)) {
    case METH_VARARGS:
        if (kw == NULL || PyDict_Size(kw) == 0)
           return (*meth)(self, arg);
        break;
```

The more I look at

```
    return (*meth)(self, arg);
```

the more I realize I don't understand it. I *think* it's returning a pointer to meth, which is a function that takes self (a locally declared pointer) and arg (a pointer passed externally into PyCFunctionCall). However, since it looks to me as though meth & self are allocated on the stack, once PyCFunctionCall exits, they will be freed, which will cause problems for whatever variables they are passed to.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's returning the return value of `meth(self, arg)`, not `meth` itself.  Note that it's derferencing the pointer with `(*meth)`, then passing in `self` and `arg` to the function at that location.

So `meth(self, arg)` will be completely evaluated before the `return` happens, and no stack variables will be returned.

Edit: when I say `meth(self, arg)`, I mean `the_function_pointed_to_by_meth(self, arg)`.

Comment: Argh!!! Thank you. I feel like an idiot, but at least I'm now an enlightened one.

Comment: That's why we're here.  And as @ams notes, don't feel too bad; function pointer syntax can be confusing.

Answer (score 4):

`meth` is a function pointer. It's returning the *result* of the function at `*meth` (the address pointed by meth) with the arguments: `(self, arg)`;

Comment: Thanks. I was really banging my head against the wall here. Now I'm feeling a little silly for asking this one, but it would've taken me a while to catch my misperception.

Answer (score 2):

`(*meth)(self, arg)` is a function **call**.

It just so happens that the *function pointer* is a local variable. The `return` merely passes  on whatever comes back from the call.

Function pointer syntax is confusing. :)

Comment: Thank you. I'm feeling a little silly now, but relievedly less confused.